# How to modify the following plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

The following figure has a few unfinished modifications.

[image: 3D]

I would like to make the first row with red color. The second row with blue color and the third row with green color.

One more thing, ['Bézier1', 'Bézier2', 'Bézier3'] are not in the center, how can I move them a little bit to the right?

One last thing, I would like to put 'Grid size' in the center.

May I get help please?

## This is the code of Python

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# create data
data_2d = [[86, 82, 80],
          [91, 88, 85],
          [97, 94, 89]]

# Convert it into an numpy array.
data_array = np.array(data_2d)

# Create a figure for plotting the data as a 3D histogram.
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Create an X-Y mesh of the same dimension as the 2D data. The floor of the plot.
x_data, y_data = np.meshgrid( np.arange(data_array.shape[1]),
                              np.arange(data_array.shape[0]) )

# Flatten out the arrays so that they may be passed to "ax.bar3d".
# ax.bar3d expects three one-dimensional arrays:
# x_data, y_data, z_data. The following call boils down to picking
# one entry from each array and plotting a bar to from
# (x_data[i], y_data[i], 0) to (x_data[i], y_data[i], z_data[i]).

x_data = x_data.flatten()
y_data = y_data.flatten()
z_data = data_array.flatten()

ax.bar3d( x_data, y_data, np.zeros(len(z_data)), 0.7, 0.7, z_data, color='r')


# Labels
ax.set_xlabel("Grid Size", labelpad=18)
ax.set_ylabel("Bézier curve-based approaches", labelpad=15, loc='center') 
ax.set_zlabel("Success Rate")

ys=['Bézier1', 'Bézier2', 'Bézier3']
xs=['30x30', '50x50', '100x100']

# Ticks
ax.set_zticks(range(0,120,20))
ax.set(xticks=range(len(xs)), xticklabels=xs,
       yticks=range(len(ys)), yticklabels=ys) 
plt.xticks(rotation = 50)


# Shape of the 3D cube 
ax.set_box_aspect(aspect=(8,8,10))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can replace this line:

```py
ax.bar3d( x_data, y_data, np.zeros(len(z_data)), 0.7, 0.7, z_data, color='r')
```

with this block:

```py
colors = ['r','b','g']
for i in [0,3,6]:
    ax.bar3d( x_data[i:i+3], y_data[i:i+3], np.zeros(len(z_data[i:i+3])), 0.7, 0.7, z_data[i:i+3], color=colors[i//3])
```

Comment: Thank you so much dear sir. The problem of colors has been solved.